# Joining Subqueries and Losing Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a large number of entries of hours spent. I am trying to get sums of hours spent based on certain characteristics by dates. My query will compete this task, but if there are no values for a certain set of characteristics on a certain date then no data will be returned for that date. I know how to solve this problem if I was joining the table with different join types, but I do not know how to do that when the join is in a where statement.

```
SELECT
t1.dates,
t1.hours1,
t2.hours2,
t3.hours3,
t4.hours4

FROM 
    (
        SELECT
        dates,
        SUM(times) AS hours1
        FROM mytable
        WHERE
        characterisics1
        GROUP By dates
    ) t1,
    (
        SELECT
        dates,
        SUM(times) AS hours2
        FROM mytable
        WHERE
        characterisics2
        GROUP By dates
    ) t2,
    (
        SELECT
        dates,
        SUM(times) AS hours3
        FROM mytable
        WHERE
        characterisics3
        GROUP By dates
    ) t3,
    (
        SELECT
        dates,
        SUM(times) AS hours4
        FROM mytable
        WHERE
        characterisics4
        GROUP By dates
    ) t4

WHERE
t1.dates = t2.dates and t1.dates = t3.dates and t1.dates = t4.dates

ORDER BY
t1.dates DESC
```

Comment: Please never use implicit joins. They are a very poor programming technique.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation . . . so much simpler:

```
SELECT dates,
       SUM(CASE WHEN characterisics1 THEN times ELSE 0 END) AS hours1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN characterisics2 THEN times ELSE 0 END) AS hours2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN characterisics3 THEN times ELSE 0 END) AS hours3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN characterisics4 THEN times ELSE 0 END) AS hours4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN characterisics5 THEN times ELSE 0 END) AS hours5
FROM mytable
GROUP By dates;
```